# Как сделать чтобы метод POST не перегружал страницу? AJAX, Spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

У меня есть форма `<form>` и *AJAX скрипт*, с помощью которого я отправляю данные в контроллер, где после добавляю их в БД.

Вот форма.

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="message" accept-charset="utf-8" ng-app="vandh" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="messageForm" novalidation="true">
    <form:textarea path="text" class="form-control" rows="1" name="message" id="message" ng-model="message" required="true"></form:textarea>
    <div style="color: black" ng-show="messageForm.message.$dirty && messageForm.message.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="messageForm.message.$error.required">
            <spring:message code="label.entermessage" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="addMessage" name="addMessage">
            <spring:message code="label.sendmessage"/>
        </button>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

AJAX скрипт

```
    <script>
$("#addMessage").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $('#message').val();
    $.ajax({ 
    type : "POST", 
    url: "/app/user/messages/${iddialog}" , 
    async : true, 
    dataType:'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data : { 
    text : text 
    } 
    }); 

    });
</script>
```

Вот контроллер на POST.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/messages/{iddialog}", method = RequestMethod.POST) public
@ResponseBody Message messages(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,
@PathVariable(value = "iddialog")int iddialog,Principal principal,@RequestParam(value = "text")String text)
{
    System.out.println("ITS HERE");
    if(checkingMessage(text)!=true){
        DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        // get current date time with Date()
        Date date=new Date();
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
        Dialog dialog=new Dialog();
        dialog.setIddialog(iddialog);
        Message mess=new Message();
        mess.setText(text);
        mess.setDialog(dialog);
        mess.setDate(dateFormat.format(date));
        mess.setMessender(principal.getName());
        this.messageService.addMessage(mess);
        this.dialogService.updateUnreadMessInfo(iddialog,principal.getName());

        System.out.println("message sent!");
        return mess;
    }else{
        Message mess1=new Message();
        return mess1;
    }
}
```

И в итоге оно мне возвращает сам объект Message
[image: Результат работы контроллера]

Как сделать чтобы метод POST работал без перезагрузки страницы? В небольшом количестве гайдов показан такой пример. Но у меня он не работает так как надо! Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: "Вот форма и скрипт." - где скрипт?

Comment: Попробую побыть вангой, вы не отменяете submit формы, либо же вы повесили обработчик на click. Посмотрите документацию тут: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: @Vartlok, спасибо за ответ, посмотрите пожалуйста мой скрипт который добавил.
при клике у меня забирает данные с textarea и передаёт в контроллер что в свою очередь возвращает мне объект.

Comment: Как рядом со словом ajax может быть фраза о презагрузке страницы? Похоже вам нужно на button повесить onclick = return fulse //////////// Чтобы форма не сабмиталась

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich вы это к тому что аякс и нужен для того чтобы всё работало без перегрузки страниц?
если да. то я это знаю, но вот когда дошло дело до реализации - возникла данная проблема

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, сейчас попробую

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, а в контроллере нет проблем?

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich когда повесил на `onclick="return false"` не работает отправка формы.

`Failed to load resource: http://localhost:8080/app/user/messages/7 the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`

Comment: @SergShapoval Все равно вы уже на правильном пути. Проверь руками откроется страница по адресу http://localhost:8080/app/user/messages/7 А Лучше воспользуйся REST клиентом и отправь на этот адрес какую то форму

Comment: Advanced REST client например для Chrome

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36060/discussion-between-serg-shapoval-and-serge-esmanovich).

Comment: Вопрос еще актуален?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, уже нет! Но всёравно спасибо за отклик

Comment: @SergShapoval тогда, пожалуйста, выберите правильный ответ, напишите свой ответ - либо удалите вопрос. Нехорошо когда неактуальный вопрос так болтается...

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться iframe:

```
<form action="..." method="post" target="my_iframe">
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>

<!-- тут будут результаты post -->
<iframe name="my_iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Или с помощью AJAX, если у вас JQuery есть:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'processing_url',
        type:'POST',
        data: {
            form_field01: field01_value,
            form_field02: field02_value
            ...
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            alert('Posted');
        }               
    });
});
```

Comment: не учите плохому

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста скрипт что добавил. 
а то умельцы модераторы "пофиксили" мой пост что удалили AJAX скрипт. Но сейчас я его уже добавил!

Comment: "не учите плохому" - это вы про iframe? Чем он плох или хуже того же XmlHttpRequest, как транспорт для AJAX? Мне честно интересно, т.к. нет опыта негативного с ним.

Comment: Не вижу, что вы делаете с ответом 'success: function(msg) {}' и эта часть 'url: "/app/user/messages/${iddialog}",' в конце у вас в html реальный id и тут только как пример?

Comment: @webaib, если вы имеете ввиду `${iddialog}` то это реальный html. обозначает id диалога. в контроллере обозначена эта переменная аннотацией `@PathVariable`

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте. Если я Вас правильно понял, то при нажатии на кнопку отправляются данные и идет отправка данных, а Вам нужно, чтоб этого релода не было. Для этого добавьте в функцию нажатия клавиши `return false;`

```
$("#addMessage").click(function(e) {   
    //code here

    return false;
});
```

Comment: у автора стоит `e.preventDefault()`, этого должно быть дсотаточно